# Can I set my XBOX One to turn the TV on at the same time?

Tags: xbox-one

I have my Playstation 3 setup to turn the TV on when the games console turns on, this is really handy.

I've been searching through my XBOX One's options and can't seem to find this option, does it exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Xbox One can turn on TV and even your sound system when you turn on the system.

You can see how to do it directly on Xbox [support site](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/live-tv/set-up-live-tv)

When you first go to the TV app it will automatically launch setup, just follow the on screen instructions and you will be all set.

If you skipped the setup or want to do it differently you can go to settings->TV & OneGuide->Devices and set it all up there as well.

If you wish to use voice commands to control your TV, Kinect will be needed. Otherwise the controller and/or smartglass can do it.

Comment: Note that Kinect is required in order for the Xbox One to turn on your TV, receiver, etc. automatically.

Comment: it is not required. it is only required for voice commands. you can still turn on and off your devices without kinect.

Comment: From what I've understood is that this functionality _requires_ an IR Blaster. If you don't own the Kinect, you'll need to get a separate IR extension cable. See [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/live-tv/use-external-ir-with-xbox-one) under "Do I need an IR extension cable?"